# pyodbc + MySQL ODBC cannot deal with Unicode database name

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, unicode, odbc, pyodbc

I am using

- pyodbc 3.0.3
- python 2.7.12
- GNU/Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- unixODBC 2.3.1
- ODBC 5.3(w) Driver

When a try to pass a Unicode database name in the connection string I get the error

> A Unicode connection string was supplied but the driver does not have a Unicode connect function

My Code looks like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyodbc
dbname = u"डाटाबेस"
cstring = "DRIVER={MySQL};SERVER=192.168.8.25;PORT=3306;DATABASE="+dbname+";UID=root;PWD=root;CHARSET=utf8;" \
                                                                          "use_unicode=1"
connect = pyodbc.connect(cstring)
```

**Edit 1:**

I have updated the pyodbc to 4.0.21 version. The above error went aways but got another problem

```
import pyodbc
dbname = u"डाटाबेस"
cstring = "DRIVER={MySQL};SERVER=192.168.2.243;PORT=3306;DATABASE="+dbname+";UID=root;PWD=support@immune;CHARSET=utf8;" \
                                                                       "use_unicode=1"
connect = pyodbc.connect(cstring, encoding='utf-8')
```

When I run this I got following error

> error=('HY000', u"[HY000] [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Unknown database '\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x9f\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb8' (1049) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show: What OS you're running. What version of the MySQL ODBC driver you're using. How you installed that driver.

Comment: pyodbc 3.0.3 is really old. Try `pip install pyodbc==4.0.21` and see if that helps.

Comment: Perhaps:  Use MySQL Connector/Python instead of pyodbc and MySQL Connector/ODBC

Comment: For now, changing library is not an option. Change in the library may lead to a lot of change in our product code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and avoid it by removing the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter from the `connect` call. My test code

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
import sys

print("Python version: " + sys.version.replace("\n", ""))
print("pyodbc version: " + pyodbc.version)
cnxn_str = (
    u"Driver=MySQL;"
    u"Server=192.168.1.144;"
    u"Port=3307;"
    u"Database=डाटाबेस;"
    u"UID=root;PWD=whatever;"
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
print("driver name: " + cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME))
print("driver version: " + cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER))
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

print(crsr.execute("SELECT txt FROM table1 WHERE id = 1").fetchval())

cnxn.close()
```

produced

```
Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
pyodbc version: 4.0.21
driver name: libmyodbc5w.so
driver version: 05.03.0010
उदाहरण
```

Comment: Change in the library version and removing `encoding='utf-8'` worked in our product code successfully. Thanks a lot.